# Poles and zeros of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Good evening, I have to determine the poles and zeros of the following function with their respective multiplicity

$$f(z) = \frac{(\cos(z))^4\sin(z^3)}{z^6(z^3+2)}$$

I know that zeros are found by setting the numerator equal to zero while the poles are found by setting the denominator equal to zero.

For $(\cos(z))^4\sin(z^3)$ I have $z=π/2 +kπ $ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$  and   $z=hπ$ for $h=0,1,2,3,\dots$

For $z^6(z^3+2)$ I have $z=0$ and $z=(-2)^\frac 13$

How do i find multiplicities?

Comment: Note that from the complex variables perspective, the multiplicities of any roots common to the numerator and the denominator will offset one another.  The root of interest here is $z=0$, shared by both.  Is it similar to an exercise worked in your class or in your textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Zeros :

   1. $\dfrac{\pi}{2} + k \pi$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}$) with multiplicity $4$.
   2. $k \pi$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}^*$) with multiplicity $3$. $k$ must be $\neq 0$ coz $0$ is a pole ($6 > 3$).

   Poles :

   1. $0$ with multiplicity $6 - 3 = 3$.
   2. $\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\dfrac{i \pi}{3} + \dfrac{2 i k \pi}{3}\right)$ ($k \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ cubic roots of $-2$) with multiplicity $1$. They are simple.

Comment: I have questions about poles:
1) 6-3 = 3 derives from the fact that 0 turns out to be both a zero and a pole so you have to subtract the respective degrees?
2) I didn't understand what was done

Comment: Yes we have to be sure that there isn't a common zeros between numerator and denominator.
In case there is one we must substract. It will be a zero if its power as zero is greater then its power as pole and vice-versa.

Comment: cube root of -2 did you write it as a complex number?

Comment: Yes. First we have to get the exponential form of $-2$ : $-2 = 2 e^{i \pi}$. And we know that the cubic roots or $r e^{i\theta}$ with $r > 0$ are :
$$\sqrt[3]{r} \exp \left(\frac{i \theta}{3} + \frac{2 i k \pi}{3}\right), k \in \{0, 1, 2\}$$

Comment: perfect, it's all very clear! thank you so much

Comment: you're welcome.